# Constantly shows Name has to refer to a struct, enum or constant even though struct has been defined

Tags: solidity, contract-development

When I attempted to compile, it threw up an error stating that when passing stakingparam in, it needed to be a struct, enum or contract, even though I thought I defined it above?

```
Contract{
struct AddLiquidityParams {
        address token0;
        address token1;
        uint24 fee;
        address recipient;
        int24 tickLower;
        int24 tickUpper;
        uint256 amount0Desired;
        uint256 amount1Desired;
        uint256 amount0Min;
        uint256 amount1Min;
    }

AddLiquidityParams stakingParam = AddLiquidityParams(0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7,0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, 0.3, 0x7858e59e0c01ea06df3af3d20ac7b0003275d4bf,34,34,address(this).balance,uSDT.balanceOf(address(this)));

function stakeCombinedLiquidity(stakingParam) public {
      liquidityM.addLiquidity(stakingParam);//liquidityM is an imported solidity file, didn't put the whole file in so I cropped only the parts I assumed were involved.
        }


}
```

Comment: Please try this `function stakeCombinedLiquidity(AddLiquidityParams stakingParam) public`

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply, but then this error shows up. This declaration shadows an existing declaration. Thanks